# Dynamic Memory Allocation for array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I've been working on a small project of mine and I got stuck at this phase. I keep getting Segfaults and I'm getting desperate. I have 2 structures

```
typedef struct {
    float time;
}Race;

typedef struct {
    char DriverName[50];
    int NoRaces;
    Race *races;
}Driver;
```

and I have to allocate memory for a single driver and then for an array of drivers after being given the number of races for each one. This is my code so far

```
Driver *allocDriver(int noRaces) {
    Driver *driver;
    driver = (Driver *)malloc(sizeof(Driver));
    driver->NoRaces = noRaces;
    driver->races = (Race *)malloc(sizeof(Race));       

    return driver;}


Driver **allocDrivers(int driversNo, int *driversRacesNo) {
    int i;
    Driver **drivers;
    drivers = (Driver **)malloc(driversNo * sizeof(Driver *));
    for(i = 0; i < driversNo; i++)
        drivers[i] = allocDriver(driversRacesNo[i]);

    return drivers;}
```

Comment: What you've posted looks fine.  Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: I already used valgrind and it says "ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)" so I don't know what could it be, I keep getting "Segmentation fault(core dumped)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm not sure, for I have no idea how you call these from your `main` nor the content of the assignment; I suspect that you need change the following line;

```
driver->races = (Race *)malloc(sizeof(Race));
```

like:

```
driver->races = (Race *)malloc(noRaces * sizeof(Race));
```

For example, your code stores 5 as number of races, but does not allocate 5 memory spaces for `struct Race` (I think, this struct is for race results); for now, it just allocates one mem-width of `struct Race`.

Comment: In main the line that gives me segfault is: TDriver** drivers = allocDrivers(3,array); I changed as you suggested but it still didn't resolve the error.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that I was sending an "int pointer" as a parameter to the function and that was giving me the error, I don't know why but that's that. Thank you for your response, you saved me from another error. :)

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) Using the dereferenced pointer to set *type-size* will always provide the right size, e.g. `driver->races = malloc(noRaces * sizeof *driver->races);` Don't forget to ***check the return*** of each allocation, e.g. `if (!driver->races) { perror ("malloc-driver->races"); return NULL; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an 'expanded' but simple example about allocation of tables of structures, compiled on ubuntu 18.04. Hope it would be self explaining and illustrative enough.For future development and practicing try to use linked list instead arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct sRace {
    float time;
}Race;

typedef struct sDriver {
    char DriverName[50];
    int NoRaces;
    Race *races;
}Driver;


typedef struct sDriversTable {
    int numdrivers;
    Driver** drivers;
} DriversTable;



Driver *allocDriver(char* name, int numraces)
{
    Driver *driver = calloc(1, sizeof(Driver));
    driver->NoRaces = numraces;
    strcpy(driver->DriverName, name);
    driver->races = calloc(numraces,sizeof(Race));
    return driver;
}

DriversTable* allocDriversTable(int numdrv)
{
     DriversTable* dt = calloc(1,sizeof(DriversTable));
     dt->numdrivers = numdrv;
     dt->drivers = calloc(dt->numdrivers, sizeof(Driver*));
    return dt;
}


void addDriver(DriversTable* drv, char* name, int numraces)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < drv->numdrivers; i++)
    {
        if( drv->drivers[i]  == NULL)
        {
            drv->drivers[i] = allocDriver(name, numraces);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void setDriverTimeForTheRace(DriversTable* drv, char* name, int raceindex, float time)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < drv->numdrivers; i++)
    {
        if( !strcmp(drv->drivers[i]->DriverName,name) )
        {
            if( raceindex < drv->drivers[i]->NoRaces )
            {
               drv->drivers[i]->races[raceindex].time = time;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("invalid race index. %d, (max. for the driver %s is %d\n",raceindex,drv->drivers[i]->DriverName, drv->drivers[i]->NoRaces -1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void printDriversTable(DriversTable* drv)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < drv->numdrivers; i++)
    {
        if( drv->drivers[i]  != NULL)
        {
            printf("Driver:%s, Races: %2d\n", drv->drivers[i]->DriverName, drv->drivers[i]->NoRaces);
            for(int j = 0; j < drv->drivers[i]->NoRaces; j++)
            {
                if(drv->drivers[i]->races[j].time > 0.0 )
                    printf("{%4.2f}", drv->drivers[i]->races[j].time);
                else
                    printf("{%4s}", "n/a");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void ReleaseResources(DriversTable** dt)
{
    DriversTable* drv = *dt;
    if( drv == NULL)
    {
      printf("nothing to release!\n");
      return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < drv->numdrivers; i++)
    {
        if( drv->drivers[i]  != NULL)
        {
            free(drv->drivers[i]->races);
            drv->drivers[i]->races = NULL;
            free(drv->drivers[i]);
            drv->drivers[i]=NULL;
        }
    }

    free(drv->drivers);
    drv->drivers = NULL;
    free(drv);
    *dt = NULL;
    printf("released!\n");
}

int main()
{
    DriversTable *drv = allocDriversTable(10);
    addDriver(drv,"Emerson", 6);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Emerson",1, 34.5);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Emerson",2, 33.6);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Emerson",7, 34.5);
    addDriver(drv,"Lake",7);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Lake",3, 21.5);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Lake",5, 22.6);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Lake",7, 23.5);
    addDriver(drv,"Palmer",8);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Palmer",4, 21.5);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Palmer",6, 22.6);
    setDriverTimeForTheRace(drv,"Palmer",7, 23.5);
    printDriversTable(drv);
    ReleaseResources(&drv);
    ReleaseResources(&drv);
    return 0;
}
```